# Laravel 5.4: Storing the 'Where' clause in a variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, where-in

I want to write a dynamic update query in Laravel which accepts arguments and can be used in whole project.

Following is my Controller function:

```
public function editquery(Request $request)
    {

    $city_id   = $request->input('city_id');    
    $city_name = $request->input('city_name');   

    $tbl  = 'city';    
    $data = ['city_name'=>$city_name];
    $wher = ('city_id',1);

    General_model::editrecord($data,$wher,$tbl);

    return redirect()->action('Admin_controller@cities_page')->with('status','Record Updated Successfully!');;

    }
```

Below is my Model function:

```
public static function editrecord($data,$wher,$tbl)
    {
      return DB::table($tbl)->where($wher)->update($data);
    }
```

The only problem here is that I cannot store the value ('city_id',1) in the $wher variable. This is the screenshot of the error:
[link to the image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vMEW.jpg)

Is there any other way to do this. Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where` method accepts an array of conditions.

```
$table  = 'city';
$conditions = [
    ['city_id', '=', '1']
];
$data = ['city_name' => $city_name];

General_model::editRecord($table, $conditions, $data);

// In your model

public static function editRecord($table, $conditions, $data)
{
    return DB::table($table)->where($conditions)->update($data);
}
```

You can also set multiple conditions.

```
$conditions = [
    ['city_id', '=', '1'],
    ['test', '=', 'test'],
];
```

**Edit**

This is the default `where` method

```
where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
```

Setting the fourth parameter to `or` will make the condition `orWhere`.

Example

```
$conditions = [
    ['city_id', '=', '1'],
    ['test', '=', 'test', 'or'],
];
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could you please tell me more about the conditions. In case how can I use the AND & OR clauses in the $conditions array?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this

```
public static function editrecord($data,$wher,$tbl)
{
  return DB::table($tbl)->where($wher)->update($data);
}
```

Since, `where` is a function; it expects 2 or 3 arguments and not just 1 argument.

You will have to pass both the arguments like so

```
public static function editrecord($data, $where_column, $where_val, $tbl)
{
  return DB::table($tbl)->where($where_column, $where_val)
                        ->update($data);
}
```

Then, in your controller function

```
$where_column = 'city_id';
$where_val = 1;

General_model::editrecord($data,$where_column,$where_val,$tbl);
```

Comment: should I change anything in my controller function?

Comment: What would I do if I need to use AND OR statement in my where clause? for example, where city_id = 1 AND city_name = london AND city_country = uk.

Comment: You need to add separate where clauses for that. Also, please ask another question for this problem. I have answered your original question. If it has solved your problem then please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @linuxartisan `where` accepts closure and arrays too.

Comment: @Sandeesh May be the OP should have been clear about that since the beginning. Since the OP has not mentioned such things in the original question, I gave my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not exactly in the style of Laravel, why would you want to create a separate static function, if such tasks are easily solved by the standard features of Eloquent / Query Builder?

Eloquent example:

app/City.php

```
<?php
class City extends Model {
    protected $table = 'city';
    protected $primaryKey = 'city_id';
    protected $fillable = ['city_name'];
}
```

In your controller:

```
City::findOrFail($city_id)->update([
    'city_name' => $city_name
]);
```

---

Query Builder example:

```
DB::table('city')->where(['city_id' => $city_id])->update([
    'city_name' => $city_name
]);
```

---

This is much easier to read, understand and support than functions that do similar things in an incomprehensible way.

Comment: I am new to Laravel. Suppose I have more than 100 tables in my database, then do I need to make 100 different Model files for each table? The example you give is good for one table but I want to write a function which I can use for all the tables. I used to do this in Codeigniter.

Comment: In general, there is nothing wrong with creating even 100 classes, if the project requires such a large number of tables. This will not affect the load, since classes are loaded only when you need to use them. With this, you will get a huge number of advantages provided by Eloquent: relationships, mutators, observers. The code will remain clean and easy to understand.